# Does a directed pseudo graph allows more than one loops for one vertex?

Tags: vertex, directed-graph, edges

In graph theory, a directed pseudograph can have multiple edges, and loops. My question is, a single vertex can have more than one loop? Or for each vertex, at most one loop is allowed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In general multiple edges between the same points in the same direction are allowed (aka *parallel arcs*). So are multiple loops on the same point, since loops are simply edges with the same start and end point.